# Manhwa/manhua where all characters have animal characteristics and the main character was a female

Tags: story-identification, manga

I don’t remember much about this but I’m pretty sure the mc was a female who had round ears at the top of her head and she was known for having a bad personality but ended up changing for the better and was able to help her village. I’m not completely sure what made her change whether it was reincarnation or something else but what I do remember was that there were two males that loved her and one of them had characteristics of a bird.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the animal traits of any of the other characters?

Comment: It looks like you've possibly made two accounts, please follow the instructions [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge them, so you may edit this question as the post owner.